# Where's the New Annex?

Tags: real-location, charles-stross, laundry-files

In *The Laundry Files*, while the actual HQ of the Laundry — Dansey House — is perpetually under (re-)construction, the Laundry's temporary HQ is "the New Annex".
[According to the author, Charles Stross](https://www.antipope.org/charlie/blog-static/2014/10/the-curse-of-laundry.html), it's located

> [...] above a department store somewhere unspecified in South London.

Can we deduce the location of the New Annex any further?

Answer (score 7):

We get a lot of details indirectly from Bob's trip to the Stacks in *The Fuller Memorandum*. He leaves from the New Annex, the Stacks were under Dansey House and haven't been moved. Bob makes the trip as a "document" using a north-south running branch line from the 1920s extensions of the MailRail track that runs under the New Annex. The MailRail goes 40MPH and the trip takes about 5 minutes to get from the New Annex back to Dansey. Assuming the New Annex is supposed to be south of the Thames, would put it somewhere near or around Clapham Common.

From the same trip we also learn that the New Annex is of 1960s construction which should narrow things down slightly too.

Comment: You've given some clues; can you draw a conclusion as well? I'm not familiar enough with London to do so.

Comment: @SQB I have very little knowledge of London I'm afraid and the only clues I can get about real-world MailRail lines or extensions put the New Annex North of Dansey which it shouldn't be and/or north of the Thames which I don't think fits either so sorry no joy. Knowing how fast the MailRail trains went would let you draw an arc of distance on a map maybe.

Comment: It's worth noting that his original idea was to have it above a branch of Woolworths (now all closed, but recently enough that documentation/information about them is probably available online). I don't know if he had a real store in mind when he decided this, but it might be worth trying to research whether there were any branches in that vicinity?